# install4j: Force a launcher (EXE) to use DLLs from bundled JRE folder

Tags: install4j

We use install4j 8.0.8 in our application. Since a new release of the application we use JRE 11.0.10 from Azul and found out that small amount of users under Windows 10 were unable to load the application with exception:  `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\thinkorswim\jre\bin\awt.dll: Can't find dependent libraries`. We were unable to reproduce the issue on our machines.

We've found in Internet some similar issues with other applications and it was said there could be a broken Windows installation (may be some DLLs were corrupted). Many pages contain mentioning of `msvcp140.dll`.

With Windows Resource Monitor we found out that our application (started with install4j native EXE launcher) loads `msvcp140.dll` from `c:\windows\system32`, but JRE 11 contains the DLL inside `bin` folder. Then we ran our application without the native launcher (just `java -jar`) and Resource Monitor showed that `msvcp140.dll` has been loaded from `jre\bin` folder.

We've asked a user to repeat and they said that the application can be launched with `java -jar`.

I've played with `PATH` environment variable and `java.library.path` via a `.vmoptions` file and I was unable to force the launcher to use DLLs from the bundled JRE.

Is it possible to tune the native launcher to make it load DLLs from the JRE bin folder?

Comment: You mention JRE 11: did the problem start occuring exactly when you switched to that version and if so, what JRE did you use perviously? Unfortunately I don't have experience with this specific problem, but that kind of information can be useful when finding the root cause and/or a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, the problem starts occurring exactly after migration from JRE 1.8.0_202 to JRE 11.0.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, executables always try to load DLLs from their directory first. That is why `java.exe` will load DLL dependencies from the bin directory before looking in the system32 directory,

The install4j launcher does not call java.exe, but starts the JVM via JNI so it's not the bin directory of the JRE but the directory of the launcher that is looked at first. Unfortunately, it is not possible to change this behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've found SetDllDirectory from WinAPI and will try to use it. Suggestion for install4j - ability to define preferred DLLs location.